# .htaccess with dynamic php - subfolder problems

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

**Necessary Knowledge**

My .htaccess file redirects like this:
domain.com/about   to  domain.com/index.php?page=about

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The "page" variable is used in a php include:

```
<?php include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/contents/".$page.".html"); ?>
```

The "contents" folder simply contains .html files that are included as the content

**Okay here's the problem:**

I have a "subfolder" in the "contents" folder with additional .html files that I need to access
Now I'm trying to redirect like this:
domain.com/subfolder/about to domain.com/index.php?page=subfolder/about

This works:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+/[^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

But now I can't access the subfolder from: domain.com/subfolder/ because there is a 'page' variable

```
<?php $page = $_GET['page']; if(!$page) { $page = 'index'; } ?>
```

Any thoughts, ideas, or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

With this, you shouldn't have to define any directory names - it rules them all out.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+/[^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

You may need to test the trailing slash though, it may work on /subfolder/ but not /subfolder

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude specific folder via

```
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/folder1/  
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/folder2/  
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+/[^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

Edit: [Link to the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond)

Answer (score 0):

Just do another check:

```
if (preg_match('/^[^\\/.]+$/', $page)) {
    $page .= '/index';
}
```

If `$page` is just `subfolder`, `/index` would be appended to have `subfolder/index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rewriteRule ^foldername/.*$ - [PT] 
rewriteRule ^foldername/.*$ - [PT]
```

before any other rewrite rule...